# Tagging migrated questions

Tags: discussion, tagging, migration

One thing I've noticed is that questions like [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3757731/convex-function-which-is-quasiconcave) end up creating an [untagged](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag whenever a migration takes place. Is this intended behavior? If not, what is the appropriate method of handling these situations?

Comment: It is, the appropriate method is finding the correct tags for the question.

Comment: Relevant post on Meta SE: [What causes a question to be tagged as (untagged)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167879/313042). Briefly, when a question is migrated from another site and none of that question's tags exist here, the question is tagged [tag:untagged]. (There are some other scenarios in which a question may end up with this tag, as detailed in the linked post.) As Asaf says, such questions should be edited to have the appropriate tags.

Comment: It is maybe worth mentioning that a question can be migrated *by regular users* only if it has one of the tags of the target site or it has an *intrinsic tag* of the target site. However, migration by mods do not have these restrictions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is intended behaviour; the Stack Exchange software isn't able to determine which tags are appropriate for a question. It will *suggest* some when you're typing the question, but it will never choose one for you. The question was tagged [function] [when it was migrated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/477250/revisions) and the [function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) tag doesn't exist here; we do have [functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) but the system isn't that smart. It will drop any tags which don't exist here (otherwise, it might accidentally create a lot of unwanted tags) and if none remain, it'll become [untagged](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) until a user edits the tags. (I have done so now, feel free to add more appropriate tags.)

The exceptions are migrations to meta sites (which happen quite frequently on Mathematics Stack Exchange); such questions will automatically be tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) instead of [untagged](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).